# Yellow spots and yellowing on railroad creeper

Tags: diagnosis, diseases, creepers

I don't know what it could be. I know it's not under watered, and I've been trying not to over water, but the spots looks weird, like if it was some kind of fungi.
[image]

[image]

Comment: is there anything on the underside of the leaf? that's where a lot of bugs hide..